# how do you use unwind segue when you have multiple ViewController that calls it

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue, unwind-segue

I started learning iOS/Swift recently and wondering how to use unwind segue.

Assume the following view controller A, B, C, E, F, X, BB, BBB

```
C -> A -> E
C -> B -> BB -> E
C -> B -> BBB -> E
C -> D -> E
F -> X -> E
```

How do I use unwind segue to go back to C or B or D from E?

Note: In ViewController E, there is only one `Back` button.

I have tried the following solution:

```
// Add this method in C, B, and D view controller
@IBAction func unwindFromE(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

This seems to work some how, but why did it unwind back to **C** for **F -> X -> E** even though in view controller F/X there's no unwindFromE method.

Comment: Are C and F two VC's in the same TabBarController?

Comment: @vacawama Yes. Both C/F is in the same TabBarController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, you can implement the unwind target `@IBAction` in multiple viewControllers and iOS will go up the call chain until it finds one.  This allows viewController `E` to return to whomever called it as long as they implement the target function `unwindFromE`.

In the case of your `E` unwind returning to `C` when the call stack was `F->X->E`, this happens when `C` and `F` are viewControllers controlled by the same `UITabBarController`.  Since `F` doesn't implement `unwindFromE`, iOS searches the other viewControllers controlled by the `UITabBarController`.  In your case, it found `C` and switched to that tab.

More information about *unwind segues* can be found in [Technical Note TN2298: Using Unwind Segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2298/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013591-CH1-DETDEST).